# Get the schema from table in prisma

Tags: database, schema, prisma

I was deleted the migration folders and schema file suddenly :|

Is there any way to get schema from tables in prisma?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can use `prisma db pull` to generate schema from your actual database. Don't forget to run `prisma generate` after that to generate the client too.

[More info in the docs as always](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection#the-prisma-db-pull-command)